# Houston Sitecore User Group - April 9th - Cortex is coming!

Tags: support, status-completed, community-event

The next Houston Sitecore User Group has been announced!

When (UTC): Monday, April 9, 2018 11:30 PM (6:30 PM local)

Where: Improving, 10111 Richmond Ave, Suite 100, Houston, TX

Cortex is coming! Cortex is coming! Are You Ready? Don't Wait! Add Machine Learning to Your Solutions Today!

Sitecore, Microsoft, Amazon, Google, IBM.. is there anyone that is NOT investing in Machine Learning? I doubt it, as the ROI can be explosive. It can provide your users real power via intelligence and automation. Cortex is coming, but don't wait to get started! Empower your applications with Machine Learning today!

Presented by Sitecore 2018 MVP - David Walker - http://radicaldave.com

If you would like to present for future meetings please reach out.

[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Houston-Sitecore-User-Group/events/bqddxnyxgbnb/)

Comment: Done. Community promotion is in effect.